# Debugging slapd error 52 (LDAP_UNAVAILABLE)

Tags: ldap, slapd

I have a server running slapd.  When I reboot the server, I am able to perform ldapsearches from the server to itself and receive correct responses for a couple of minutes.  But after a couple minutes have elapsed, the server starts responding with:

```
ldap_bind: Server is unavailable (52)
        additional info: <NODE> is temporarily out of service
```

It will stay like that indefinitely (there's nothing temporary about it).  I have not been able to find anything in the logs that help identify what the underlying issue could be.  I added "loglevel -1" to the slapd.conf file so that everything would be output to the logs.

Are there any recommendations for what I can use to troubleshoot why the server began responding like that?

Comment: have you checked if the ldap service started properly after the reboot? Maybe there is a delay during the start process. Can you re-create the issue with a ldap restart or it only happens on a reboot? does the ldap service has any other dependencies?

Comment: Restarting ldap does not recreate the issue, but only a system restart.  The processes appear to be running fine ('ps -ef | grep slapd' shows what I expect).  I also checked the PIDs of the slapd process during a working ldapsearch and a failed ldapsearch and confirmed they were the same.  Thus the ldap process did not restart during the transition from working to failing.

Comment: Are you using systemd? centos? Then try this `systemctl -l status slapd` to see if it gives more information. If you are using systemd then also add `After=network.target` to make sure ldap starts after all the network services are up. This looks like a service dependency issue.